# My Online messaging system

Tags: php

I want to create a messaging system, here is my table:

```
(customers) userid int 11 primary key auto increment, username varchar 255, password varchar 255

(messages) mid int 11 primary key auto increment, from_id index customer.userid, to_id index customer.userid, message text
```

My question is if my session `userid` is 11 how to display all the messages that are sent to my id?

What is the right code to use?

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT 
                                       message.*, customer.username AS from_id
                                  FROM 
                                        message
                                  INNER JOIN
                                        customer
                                  ON
                                        customer.userid = message.from_id
                                  ");

        $stmt->execute();

        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: You probably want to tag this as SQL as the question is really about the query.

It looks like you have done the join correctly but you have not added a filter. What you probably need to do is add WHERE customer.userid = 11 at the end.

Comment: How about the other userid for example i log in using anothet userid how to display all the messages that is sent to that userid

Comment: The quick and dirty way is to construct the query in a string like you did there, the better way is to use a prepared statement with a parameter to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities . You could add to the end of your string there . "where message.userid = " . "11"; and replace 11 with whatever your id is. You did not supply enough code for me to use your actual variables.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe you need is a "Where" clause in your query. Adding "where userid = 11" at the end will do exactly what you asked in the question above.

If the userid is a parameter you should look at this PAQ for how to do that, because that is a different question.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)